# Problem in the localhost phpmyadmin.Error while working with template cache

Tags: xampp, localhost

I installed Xampp version 7.3 and got the following errors in localhost.

Error while working with template cache: Failed to write cache file "C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\tmp/\twig/32/3246783701c6a1eba6b25763c71b8928a9b04d7245adcb0f91cd66ffbc768b2e.php".

Does anyone know what this means and how to fix it?

Comment: @Ojava Even as Admin it didn't work for me. [My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71316571/error-while-working-with-template-cache-for-access-denied-folder-as-admin-and-no)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, I tried to run XAMPP Control Panel on Administrator mode ,This is solved the problem for me